# Program ignores some functions in order

Tags: c, arrays, fgets

I've created a variable-sized array (VLA) and I want to fill it with using `fgets` functions in a `for` loop. However program passes the some functions and it strangely ignores the first `fgets` action.

My code is;

```
void editorMain(void)
{
    printf("Please enter the number of items:  ");
    scanf("%u", &itemQuantity);
    printf("\n\n");

    char itemNames[itemQuantity][ITEM_NAME_LEN+1];

    memset(&itemNames, 0, sizeof(itemNames));

    printf("Please enter the names of items:  \n");

    char line[ITEM_NAME_LEN+1];

    memset(&line, 0, sizeof(line));

    for (int i = 0; i < itemQuantity; ++i) {
        printf("#%d:  ", i + 1);

        memset(&line, 0, sizeof(line));

        fgets(line, ITEM_NAME_LEN+1, stdin);

        for (int a = ITEM_NAME_LEN+1; a >= 0; --a) {
            if (line[a] == '\n') {
                line[a] = 0;
            }

            else;
        }

        snprintf(itemNames[i], ITEM_NAME_LEN+1, "%s", line);
    }
...
}
```

And it outputs;

```
Please make a choice:  2

Please enter the number of items:  4


Please enter the names of items:  
#1:  #2:  Marlboro
#3:  Parliament
#4:  Winston

Please enter the prices of items:  
#1:  25
#2:  950
#3:  1000
#4:  800
  ................... AVAILABLE ITEMS oo

         #           Item Name          Price
         =           =========        =======

         1.                           0.25 TL
         2.           Marlboro        9.50 TL
         3.         Parliament       10.00 TL
         4.            Winston        8.00 TL

  Enter your item selection:
```

What's your suggestion?

Comment: Usual problem; the `scanf()` leaves the newline in the buffer, so the `fgets()` reads up to the newline, which confuses you.  Probably best to use `fgets()` throughout and `sscanf()` to convert the first line into a number.  There are a bazillion or so other questions about this sort of issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I run my program, fgets() is ignored and scanf() doesn't input data to structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303008/when-i-run-my-program-fgets-is-ignored-and-scanf-doesnt-input-data-to-stru).  I doubt if this is the canonical question that this is the duplicate of, but it did show up in the related list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scanf("%u"` call reads up to the newline character, but leaves that character in the input stream. When you call your first `fgets`, it just reads that newline character and gives you an empty string.

There are many ways to clear the input stream, in this case you could just add a dummy call to `fgets` after your `scanf`.

Comment: Thanks, it is the solution of my problem.